# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: userdata

Tags: laravel

The error message I get is:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: userdata
```

I know these things get asked a lot. I have searched Google and here and I have already tried suggested answers to no avail.

**Controller:**

```php
public function index()
{
    $userdata = EditUserModel::all()->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.userman')->with(['userdata' => $userdata])->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

**Route:**

```php
Route::resource('admin.userman', 'EditUserController');
```

**Model:**

```php
public class EditUserModel extends Model
{
    public $table = "users";

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'email',
        'role',
        'password'       
    ];
}
```

**View:**

```html
@foreach($userdata as $data)
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->created_at }}</td>                        
            <td>{{ $data->role }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->status }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.auseredit',$data->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
@endforeach
```

The output should be a table listing the contents of the users table from the database. but i'm getting undefined variable error.

Comment: Did you check by printing the variable using dd($userdata); If it's empty an if(!empty($userdata)) would work.

Comment: have your tried this `view('admin.userman',compact("userdata"))` instead of this `view('admin.userman')->with(['userdata' => $userdata])`... also your tbody should be outside the foreach loop

Comment: @arun no, the table is not empty..@danish-khan-l  yes i have done the compact thing and still doesn't work.

Comment: `EditUserModel::paginate(5);` you should do like this.

Comment: @JasonRoyIrabagon you accepted Addweb Solution's answer thanks to him that also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

**Controller:**

```php
public function index()
{
    $userdata = EditUserModel::all()->paginate(5);
    $i = (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5;
    return view('admin.userman',compact('userdata','i'));
}
```

**Route:**

```php
Route::resource('admin.userman', 'EditUserController');
```

**Model:**

```php
public class EditUserModel extends Model
{
    public $table = "users";

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'email',
        'role',
        'password'       
    ];
}
```

**View:**

```html
@if(isset($userdata))
  @foreach($userdata as $data)
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
              <td>{{ $data->email }}</td>
              <td>{{ $data->created_at }}</td>                        
              <td>{{ $data->role }}</td>
              <td>{{ $data->status }}</td>
              <td>
                  <a href="{{ route('admin.auseredit',$data->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
              </td>
              <td>
                  @csrf
                  @method('DELETE')
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: thanks karan..your suggestion works..but my problem now is that the table is not empty it has several records in it..

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function index()
{
        $userdata = EditUserModel::all()->paginate(5);
        $page = array('i'=>(request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
        return view('admin.userman',compact('userdata','page'));
}
```

Comment: the problem was stated above..an error exception indicating an undeclared variable in the but the variable was declared in the controller.  the solution provided by @Karan resolve it the table header was shown but no data is being posted on the page if i remove the @if(isset) it goes back to the error being $userdata not declared